# Why is my google custom search API call from python not working?

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-custom-search, google-search-api, bad-request

When I run the following code I am getting an error response (see the second snippet). I have checked and made sure the GOOGLE_SEARCH_KEY and the SEARCH_ENGINE_ID are valid and I have billing set up properly. I have removed sensitive data from the error message and put in placeholders. What could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
            from googleapiclient.discovery import build

            try:

                api_key = GOOGLE_SEARCH_KEY
                search_engine_id = SEARCH_ENGINE_ID
                query = "test"
                num_results = 100

                service = build("customsearch", "v1", 
                         developerKey=api_key)

                response = service.cse().list(
                    q=query,
                    cx=search_engine_id,
                    num=num_results
                ).execute()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

> File "x.py", line 34, in search ).execute() ^^^^^^^^^ File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py",
> line 130, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py",
> line 938, in execute raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=%22Software%22&cx=<SEARCH_ENGINE_ID>&num=100&key=<API_KEY>&alt=json
> returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details:
> "[{'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'domain':
> 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: That is the full error I am getting from the API call, it's not giving me any other data.  I have wrapped the whole thing in a try and except block and exception is the one I pasted on the second snippet.

Comment: _I have wrapped the whole thing in a try and except block_ Then you have not shown us your real code, because the posted code does not have such a try/except block.

Comment: It is very hard to help when you do not show your real code.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post to include the try except block.

Comment: Can you show the traceback from the exception? You can print this by adding `import traceback; print(traceback.format_exc())` after `print(e)`, or by removing the try/except block.

Comment: Yeah, the typical problem with "wrap a big section of code in a try/except" is that the `print(e)` in the except block doesn't tell us WHERE the exception happened.  It's better to take the try/except out and just let the exception happen, so the traceback message will say exactly which line of code triggered the error.

Comment: Ok the full traceback now that I added that traceback code is 

  File "x.py", line 34, in search
    ).execute()
      ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)

and then it prints me that error I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Change `num_results = 100` to `num_results = 10`.